# How to add characters to the end of a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a string stored as `tempP`, and since I have no experience with C++. I was wondering how I would add a word to the string. So for example in C# it would be

```
tempP = tempP + "addtext";
```

Comment: What is the type of `tempP`?

Comment: Did you try `tempP = tempP + "addtext"`?

Comment: tempP is stored as a string.

Comment: If `tempP` is a `std::string`, you can use `tempP += "addtext";` or `tempP = tempP + "addtext";` (or any of many other methods to add characters...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as you expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string tempP("temp");
    tempP += "addText";    // the same as tempP = tempP + "addtext";
    std::cout << tempP << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `tempaddText`

Comment: should you cout << tempP.c_str()?

Comment: @lzprgmr Not necessary, `std::string` can be used with `std::cout`.

Comment: std::string tempP("temp");

Answer (score 4):

```
std:string temp("something");
temp = temp + "addtext";
```

Now temp is somethingaddtext.

Comment: or you can use += or append() method.